# How do you add applets in Gnome 3/Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: gnome, indicator, applet

I have installed Gnome Ubuntu 15.04 AMD64 on my Dell XPS 13.  I would like to add an indicator next to the wifi and sound icons that shows network bandwidth usage.

It appears that netspeed fits the bill, but I cannot figure out how to add applets.  I have tried holding Alt and right clicking in the area to the left of the icons, but nothing happens.  I believe the correct term for the area I want to add this applet to is the Gnome panel, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Application Indicators are available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)

Comment: @xangua he want's to install it, not know what there is...

Comment: Perhaps not a duplicate, but you can't just simple add indicators the way you used way back in Gnome 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to extentions.gnome.org - I have to use firefox not Chrome.

[NetSpeed is here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/104/netspeed/)

Click the On / Off slider, so it goes on and it will be installed:

[image]

Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `r` then press enter.

It should be in the top panel.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much!